# PyQt QTimer problem QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread

Tags: python, pyqt5

I had an annoying problem with my PyQt app, but I fixed it. I present it here so other newbies can avoid making the same mistake.

My PyQt app had a class derived from QGraphicsScene. The scene adds about a hundred QPixMaps to itself.

Trouble was, when the program exited, I got about a hundred of the following error messages:

```
QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

and this is my code:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
     
    class ModelHexMap(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
     
        def __init__(self, tilePath, mapPath, parent=None):
            QtGui.QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent)
            self.commonInit(tilePath, mapPath)
     
        def commonInit(tilePath, mapPath):
            # make calls to self.addPixmap()
     
    class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
     
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
     
            # the following causes the error
            self.ModelHexMap = ModelHexMap("game.til", "game.map")
            # this is the correct way
            self.ModelHexMap = ModelHexMap("game.til", "game.map", self)
     
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        myapp = MyForm()
        myapp.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
how can i fix it?
```

Comment: if the data is not enough i can provide more info

Answer (score 0):

I don't put any effort into chasing exit crashes anymore--just use pg.exit() and be done with it.

(but if you do happen to find a bug in pyqtgraph, don't hesitate to open an issue on github)